# How to grep for multiple non-greedy matches in HTML text?

Tags: html, regex, grep

I have a long line like this:

```
<div class="interesting">This is interesting1</div><div class="not interesting">Some text</div><div class="interesting">This is interesting2</div><div class="not interesting">Some more text</div>
```

How can I extract the following:

```
This is interesting1
This is interesting2
```

from the above text using grep? Any suggestions?

```
cat temp | grep -o "<div class=\"interesting\">.*?</div>"
```

does not seem to be giving out anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat temp | grep -P -o "<div class=\"interesting\">(.*?)</div>"
```

Parenthesis match the items items inside that html tag.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this already but for some reason, this does not give me any output.

Comment: +1 I modified your answer to include the `-P` flag and now it works. Thanks!